# VMware ESXi vSphere API using Java

Tags: java, api, vmware, vsphere, esxi

I use ESXi 6.0 and I want to use the vSphere API to create a VM .

And I use the example code form [CreatVM](https://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/vm/CreateVM.java#l30)

But it show the exception as following .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.RemoteException: VI SDK invoke exception:com.vmware.vim25.RestrictedVersion
at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:122)
at com.vmware.vim25.ws.VimStub.createVM_Task(VimStub.java:749)
at com.vmware.vim25.mo.Folder.createVM_Task(Folder.java:130)
at com.vmware.vim25.mo.samples.vm.CreateVM.main(CreateVM.java:93)
```

And my java environment is built from this [Getting started with vSphere API using Java](http://vthinkbeyondvm.com/getting-started-with-vsphere-api-using-java/)

How should I fix it ? Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Restricted version? Licensing issue?

Answer (score 0):

This exception comes with one of the below reasons,

1) Using different user agent didn't have supported operation(Create VM,powerON VM..) to perform.

2) ESXi server license may expiry which does not allow to create & powerON VM....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free version of ESXi, the API is limited to read-only operations. You can recognize that license because it shows up as "vSphere 6.0 Hypervisor Licensed for N CPUs"

From the [VMWare knowledge base](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1023990):

> Notes:
>   vCLI, PowerCLI, and vSphere SDK for Perl are limited to read-only access for the free vSphere Hypervisor edition. To enable full functionality of vCLI on a VMware ESXi host, the host must be licensed with vSphere Essentials, vSphere Essential Plus, vSphere Standard, vSphere Advanced, vSphere Enterprise, or vSphere Enterprise Plus.

The article talks about Perl, but the limitation is valid for all languages and SDKs.

The `restrictedVersion` error is an indication of this limitation. To use the full API you have either to pay for a license (all will give you access to the API), or to use vSphere during its first 60 days trial mode.